# Can't stop SwiftMailer Exceptions Being Displayed to Browser in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I am using Laravel for a site. I have a page where users can contact me. This sends me an email using the SwiftMailer bundle. It has just been brought to my attention that the following error is seen when trying to send a message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException'
```

Exception thrown from here `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yooies_site/bundles/swiftmailer/library/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php on line 176`

Code at this location is:

```
  throw new Swift_TransportException(
'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "' .
$this->_username . '" using ' . $count . ' possible authenticators'
);
```

The cause of the error is not a worry (I found out that I had change my mail password and forgot to change in my sites email config)

The issue I have is that I have Laravel setup to log any exceptions and NOT display them on the main page. I have the following setup in my error.php config file

```
'detail' => false,
'log' => true,
```

Why then is my site showing the exception on the page instead of a 500 error?

Full stack trace here (Note I have removed my sites real name and replaced with 'site'

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' 
with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info+site.com" using 2 possible authenticators' 
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/bundles/swiftmailer/library/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php:176 

Stack trace: 
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/bundles/swiftmailer/library/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(307): Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(Object(Swift_SmtpTransport)) 
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/bundles/swiftmailer/library/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(124): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand() 
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/bundles/swiftmailer/library/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() 
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/application/libraries/personal/mailer.php(55): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) 
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/application/config/error.php(91): Personal\Mai in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/bundles/swiftmailer/library/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php on line 176
```

Laravel version is L3.

Bundle URL here http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/swiftmailer

Comment: Presumably Laravel will have to do something, on the basis that the exception is uncaught - it won't finish the code in the controller even if Laravel were to do its own `catch`. Can you wrap the call with a `try` and log if you are in live, and re-`throw` if you are in dev?

Comment: The thing is, Laravel handles this already but for some reason not for this swift mailer exceptions. I'd prefer to get to root cause within laravel and modify to ensure exception is caught

Comment: OK, +1. I'm not familiar with Laravel, but if you have any of your own controller code for this bundle, it might be worth editing it in. Or does this bundle work on its own, routing and all?

Comment: This is an open source bundle. It would be good if i could work out how laravel actually prevents exceptions being output. I can then hopefully trace the problem myself

Comment: Anything in the docs? I've not seen the docs myself, so not sure how thorough they are.

Comment: Maybe there's additional config in bundles/swiftmailer/config that overwrites your application/config settings. Though silly, it's worth checking - I had a similar issue with some bundle. Other thing is that I couldn't run _swiftmailer_ bundle, went with _messages_ which also uses swiftmailer class for sending emails, but worked for me better.

Comment: doesn't have a config override. Bundle URL here http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/swiftmailer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swiftmailer doesn't touch any configuration that's responsible for showing errors. Among the recommendations for production servers is to have `display_errors = Off` and `display_startup_errors = Off`, which can be set in `php.ini`, `httpd.conf`, `.htaccess`, `.user.ini`, etc, or even using `ini_set()`. You should make sure these directives are correctly set.

I'm not familiar with how Laravel handles exceptions and errors, but it looks like the `Swift_TransportException` is thrown outside of Laravel's error-handling process. Can you point out where in the flow of the application the exception is thrown? Maybe a stack-trace?

PS: Just a tip: Things like sending emails are better not done during a request at all. You could offload it to some sort of queue, and have another process on the server handle it. You could take a look at [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) for this.

**update**

Looking at the stack-trace, it seems Laravel does catch the exception because `Log::exception();` is invoked (in `application/config/error.php` line 91). But the trace doesn't reveal how it got there. Maybe you can run it on a development machine where you have [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) installed. Xdebug will give you a more precise stack-trace when the exception is throws, ending with `public/index.php` (where the request started).

Comment: Stack trace added to question

Comment: Ahh! I've just worked it out!! At error.php 91 I have a logging function which reacts to any exceptions caught. In here I send an email to myself. So its catching an email error, and then trying to send an email, which creates another exception. Im gonna give you the bounty for this as it helped direct me to the answer - knew it had to be something silly I'd overlooked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice catch! The second exception will indeed be thrown outside of Laravel's error-handling process :) Feel free to edit my answer with your final findings!